# Thymeleaf to madal jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal

Have a nice day, everyone!
I am doing a training project on SpringBoot + Thymeleaf + BootStrap4 + jQuery.

Faced a problem - I can’t get the entity fields in the bootstrap modal window for changing records in the table.

This is my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" th:data-id="${userTable.id}" th:data-username="${userTable.username}" th:data-newPassword="${newPassword}"onclick="doSomething(this.getAttribute('data-id'), this.getAttribute('data-username'), this.getAttribute('data-newPassword'));">Edit</button>
```

This is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-id">Id: </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="modal-username" class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="modal-newPassword" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-newPassword"></input>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething(userid, userUsername, userNewPassword) {
        alert(userid + ", " + userUsername + ", " + userNewPassword) //working
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-id').text(userid)
        modal.find('.modal-username').val(userUsername)
        modal.find('.modal-newPassword').val(userNewPassword)
    } </script>
```

By the button I call the jquery function to which I transfer the user data. In the function I want to fill the bootstrap 4 modal window.

I tried different options. An alert with several parameters works, but a modal window doesn’t!
I will be glad of any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is decided:

Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
    data-target="#exampleModal"
    data-toggle="modal"
    th:data-userId="${userTable.id}"
    th:data-userUsername="${userTable.username}"
    th:data-newPassword="${newPassword}"
    onclick="fillingModal(this.getAttribute('data-userId'), this.getAttribute('data-userUsername'), this.getAttribute('data-newPassword'));">
Edit </button>
```

Script:

```
    function fillingModal(userId, userUsername, newPassword, userRoles) {

    $("#modal-id").text("Edit user Id: " + userId);
    $("#modal-username").val(userUsername);
    $("#modal-newPassword").val(newPassword);

}
```

Bootstrap4 Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-id">Id: </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="modal-username"
                           class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="modal-newPassword" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-newPassword">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing all the values are arguments to the function, you can do it in a more cleaner way:

```
onclick="fillingModal(event)"
```

Then in Javscript:

```
function fillingModal(event){
  var useId = $(event).data("userId");
//and others...

}
```

Comment: MohamedSanaulla, it didn’t work for me! Perhaps the point is in the version of thymeleaf ... not sure! Writes in onclick = "fillingModal (event)" that "event" is deprecated!